# Where to find Street View House Number example for CNN

Tags: tensorflow

At the end of the [Convolutional Neural Network example](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html) there is an exercise to modify the program to use the Street View House Numbers (SVHN) data set. I have been working on this for the past few days and am finding it quite difficult to modify, especially since the data formats are different and the SVHN data set has variably sized images.

This example would be extremely valuable to build an image classifier for use in a production environment. Any ideas where I could get this completed exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered in the tensorflow mailing list but in case others end up with this question the data can be fetched from the [standford website](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/).

The format is in matlab but can be read in python with scipy with [scipy.io.loadmat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html)

Comment: Any chance you have code that could replace the read_cifar10 function cifar10_input.py? If not I would be more than happy to share after writing it.

Comment: Did you try to read it? `scipy.io.loadmat` fails as it doesn't support `v7.3`. And it is not possible to read it with `h5py` or `tables` as  uses some MATLAB data structure, rather than arrays.